# Assistance with Lua functions

Tags: function, lua

As noted before, I'm relatively new to lua, but again, I learn quick.  The last time I got help here, it helped me immensely, and I was able to write a better script.  Now I've come to another question that I think will make my life a bit easier.  I have no clue what I'm doing with functions, but I'm hoping there is a way to do what I want to do here.  Below, you'll see an example of code I have to do to strip down some unneeded elements.  Yeah, I realize it's not efficient in the least, so if anyone else has a better idea of how to make it much more efficient, I'm all ears.  What I would like to do is create a function with it so that I can strip down whatever variable with a simple call of it (like stripdown(winds)).  I appreciate any help that is offered, and any lessons given.  Thanks!

```
winds = string.gsub(winds,"%b<>","")  
winds = string.gsub(winds,"%c"," ")  
winds = string.gsub(winds,"  "," ")  
winds = string.gsub(winds,"  "," ")  
winds = string.gsub(winds,"^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1)")  
winds = string.gsub(winds,"&nbsp;","")  
winds = string.gsub(winds,"/ ", "(")
```

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning it into a function is the easy part.

```
function stripdown(winds)
    winds = string.gsub(winds,"%b<>","")  
    winds = string.gsub(winds,"%c"," ")  
    winds = string.gsub(winds,"  "," ")  
    winds = string.gsub(winds,"  "," ")  
    winds = string.gsub(winds,"^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1)")  
    winds = string.gsub(winds,"&nbsp;","")  
    winds = string.gsub(winds,"/ ", "(")  
    return winds
end
```

This function as written does produce and abandon a lot of intermediate string results, which can be a relatively expensive operation. It is almost certainly worth careful study of the documentation for [string.gsub()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) and its [pattern language](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1). It should be possible to do at least some of what you've specified in fewer operations.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping to lessen the work it has to do.  I have an idea of how to do that, too, but this is definitely a step in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This should be slightly better:

```
function stripdown(str)
    return (str:gsub("%b<>","")  
               :gsub("[%c ]+"," ")  
               :gsub("^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1)")  
               :gsub("&nbsp;","")  
               :gsub("/ ", "("))
end
```

Reduced 3 of the patterns down to one;
The brackets around the return expression reduce the output to only the first return value from gsub.

Answer (score 3):

For a function like this, I'm a huge fan of object syntax:

```
function stripdown(winds)
    winds = winds:gsub("%b<>","")  
                 :gsub("%c"," ")  
                 :gsub("  "," ")  
                 :gsub("  "," ")  
                 :gsub("^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1)")  
                 :gsub("&nbsp;","")  
                 :gsub("/ ", "(")  
    return winds
end
```

This version is no more or less efficient than the other, but there's a lot less syntactic noise and I find it easier to see what's going on.

There's a technical reason for not simply returning the big expression, and that's because `gsub` returns two results.
Assigning it to `winds` "adjusts" away the (unwanted) second result, and the function returns only the string.